# Automating the assignment of multiple built-in Azure policy

Tags: azure, powershell, terraform, azure-policy

I am trying to assign multiple built-in azure policies to my azure environment with a single click. How can I do that in a more elegant way?

I have tried the below ways.

1. Create a policy definition and build an image using packer. Deploy the image via terraform
2. I have passed the policy definition ID  to the resource group in terraform script as similar to the below script.

```
    resource "azurerm_policy_assignment" "example" {
      name = "test"
      policy_definition_id = data.azurerm_policy_definition.example.id
      scope = "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/MyManagementGroup"
    }
```

How to pass multiple definition policy definition ids? Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could break it down into child modules, use the parent module to call separate child modules, with this you can `reuse`/`mix-n-match` etc. For e.g. lets say each child module manages only 1 resource type such as `/modules/policy-definitions` manages Azure_RM policy definitions.

Now, the parent module calls all child modules and it's where we set input variable values if required by the child modules.

here's the parent module calling `/modules/MyPolicy-assignments` and setting  those values for 4 input variables.

```
module "policy_assignments" {
  source = "./modules/MyPolicy-assignments"

  tag_governance_policyset_id             = "${module.policyset_definitions.assetTag_governance_policyset_id}"
  iam_governance_policyset_id             = "${module.policyset_definitions.iam_governance_policyset_id}"
  security_governance_policyset_id        = "${module.policyset_definitions.security_governance_policyset_id}"
  data_protection_governance_policyset_id = "${module.policyset_definitions.data_protection_governance_policyset_id}"
  AD... = "${module.policyset_definitions.AD...}"
}
```